# How to upgrade kernel from terminal in Linux Mint 18?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, upgrade

I like the beauty of Linux Mint 18's `mintupdate` (a part of [Mint utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint#Software_developed_by_Linux_Mint)), which provides me with the latest stable kernel security updates, like today (*2016-Dec-01*):

[image: mintupdate]

Clues might be in the `mintupdate`'s Python script located in:

```
/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/mintUpdate.py
```

However, I didn't manage to find any so far. Possibly due to the fact, I don't understand Python.

Providing, I would like to do this over terminal in a Bash script.

Disclaimer: I don't want to install the latest kernel available on [Kernel.org](https://kernel.org/).
I would like to install the same as `mintupdate` suggests.

**EDIT1**:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list

(empty)
```

---

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

output, separated by file:

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free

deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps games

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main

deb http://packages.linuxmint.com sarah main upstream import backport 
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ xenial partner

deb-src http://packages.linuxmint.com sarah main upstream import backport 
deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ xenial partner

deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam

deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

Comment: I am not that familiar with Mint; as it is Debian based, does it accept Debian backports? In the Debian 8 boxen that I have, I have kernel 4.7 from Debian backports. I usually do not worry about the gory details of the programs to keep the maintenance of the system, I just worry about `/etc/apt/sources.list` and having the correct files (if needed) in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (and apt preferences).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It is not Debian based (only LMDE), normal versions are Ubuntu based.

Comment: Ubuntu/Debian, take it as being from the same tree. it was a generalisation, the comment still applies. I am rather curious, while some part of the comments are indeed redundant, why the sudden cleanup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your apt files, it is obvious you are using ubuntu backports. More interestingly yet, you already have backports configured, see the line:

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

For selecting the kernel you are interested in, use -t to select the xenial-backports. Do:

```
apt-get update
apt-cache search -t xenial-backports linux-image (or a similar variation for the kernel packages)
apt-get install -t xenial-backports linux-image-xxx
```

If you are building the kernel, or kernel modules for some reason, you will also need to install the new version of `linux-headers` and `linux-kbuild`

If using `open-vm-tools`, you probably need to install the new version:

```
apt-get install -t xenial-backports open-vm-tools
```